# How to localize date format in Dygraphs

Tags: dygraphs

I'm about to use dygraphs in non-english language environment. In order to provide most user friendly interface, I would like to change date format localization.

Is there any way to achieve this with dygraphs ?

Best,
Michal

Answer (score 0):

Dygraphs offer an option for rendering the x-axis labels via [`axisLabelFormatter`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#axisLabelFormatter), which is a function that should transform value from the axis to a string. Depending on your data, first argument is either a number or a Javascript `Date` object, which can be formatted any way you like.

This snippet displays dates as *MONTH YEAR* in Czech.

```
g = new Dygraph(…, …, {
        axes: {
            x: {
                axisLabelFormatter: function(date, granularity, opts, dygraph) {
                    var months = ['leden', 'únor', 'březen', 'duben', 'květen',
                                  'červen', 'červenec', 'srpen', 'září',
                                  'říjen', 'listopad', 'prosinec'];
                    return months[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getFullYear();
                }
               }
              }
    });
```

You could get a lot more fancy, for real usage you should probably use the `granularity` argument to display different precision as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way of localization is redefine internal Dygraph variable

```
// after include dygraph and before ... = new Dygraph (...
var SHORT_MONTH_NAMES_ = ['leden', 'únor', ..., 'listopad', 'prosinec'];
```